# How much space do I need for an iPad for iOS programming?

Tags: ios, ipad, development

What is a good storage space for an iPad for iOS programming? Should I purchase a 16 GB model or a 32 GB model? Would 16 GB be to small for iPad and iOS programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need as much space as your app requires to be installed, which depends entirely on the type of apps you are developing and the number of apps that you intend to install at one time.

iOS uses at most approximately 4 GB, leaving 12 GB on the 16 GB model. The largest apps on the App Store are rarely larger than a couple of gigabytes, so this would be fine for that.